# How to test your speaker?

Tags: skype, speakers

I'm trying to use skype in ubuntu 11.
But it fails.
It seems something is wrong with my speak driver, how can i fix it?
It's ok in Windows.

Comment: What exactly means "something went wrong"? are you receiving a driver specific message? or just can't get your audio from/to skype?

Answer (score 2):

You can test your speakers in `sound preferences`:

[image]

Regarding sound issues the Ubuntu Wiki has a [SoundTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) that checks in detail any issues regarding sound.

Comment: "SoundTroubleshootingProcedure" does not check speakers with sound.  There is no test speakers in 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

you can test it using gstreamer properties just press alt-F2 then enter

```
gstreamer-properties
```

it should look like this just press test on default output

[image]

Comment: This only tests one speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Also it is worth being aware that there is a tick box in your skypoe options box to stop skype messing up your sound options as well which if you are running pulse audio it sometimes does. I have found that deselecting the option here helps where it says Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels.

[image: turn this off!]

More info here from the skype site

[skype for linux](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA10964/How-can-I-adjust-my-audio-settings-to-run-Skype-for-Linux)

Let us know how you get on

Comment: Good one andybleaden!

Comment: years of frustration taught me that trick..oh and google! thanks :)